# Rebus puzzle (62ND S MAKE A single)

Tags: rebus

Here is a rather simple rebus puzzle:

> 62ND S MAKE A single

Comment: I don't get why this question gets a bunch of downvotes... While it was upvoted at first.

Comment: @nicael which is other question?

Comment: Lol, that was such an old comment, @Rahul... I don't even remember what I did mean that time :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> 60 seconds make a single minute
>
>  62nd = 60 second, followed by S MAKE A single (in small text)

Comment: Could you please explain how you got that answer?

Comment: @CoolGuy Sixty second s make a single minute (minute=small).

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code , I still didn't get it.,

Comment: @CoolGuy 62nd (sixty-second) + s
        => Sixty Second(s)

Then... As everything is in bold and single is in lowercase  that is small or minute(synonym of small)

Putting both together we get 
.
.
Sixty seconds make a single minute!